# Contour plot of rectangular matrix in polar coordinates matlab

Tags: matlab, contour, polar-coordinates, contourf

I have a rectangular matrix of dimensions `(r,theta)` and I am trying to display its contours on polar coordinates:

[image: (r,theta) contour plot of a rectangular matrix]

This method basically 'wraps' the contours onto polar coordinates, which produces a discontinuity at 0°. I am looking for a way to avoid this. Any ideas on how to transform this matrix in order to plot continuous contours?

Comment: Could you provide the code that generated the above? I suspect that if you replicated the first theta column (theta=0) at the end (theta=360) the plot would become smoother.

Comment: I'm using something like this:

`r = 100:200:900;  
th = (0:360).*2*pi/360;  
[TH,R] = meshgrid(th,r);
[x,y] = pol2cart(TH,R);

%% DISPLAY
h = polar(x,y);
hold on
delete(h)
contourf(x,y,M,10,'color','none')
[c,h] = contour(x,y,M,[1.5 1.5],'k');
clabel(c,h,[1.5 1.5],'labelspacing',800)`

where M is a (r,th) matrix.

I've tried adding the first column at 360° and it creates continuous but very angular contours.

Comment: If you haven't solved this, it would be interesting to ask Mathworks tech support (that's partly why you pay the big bucks for a license, right?).  And then please report back here with the answer.

Comment: Agreed, Rich! I will contact them